# Client-side validation not working in Mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class property
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PostedBy { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the mobile no")]
    public Int64 Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the cshtml page on which validation needs to be implemented.

```
@model Property.Models.property


      @ {  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserProperty.cshtml"; }


<h2>Post Property</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Listings", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{    

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <article class="bs-docs-social-body">
            <section class="container">
                <div class="form-box-container">
                    <div class="form-box-left">
                        <h5>* Name :</h5>
                         @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)*@
                         @Html.Editor("Name", @ViewData["Name"])
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" class="postedby" name="postedby" id="Builder" value="Builder" /> I am the Builder
             <input type="radio" class="postedby" name="postedby" id="Agent" value="Agent" /> I am the Agent
             <input type="radio" class="postedby" name="postedby" id="Owner" value="Owner" /> I am the Owner

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-box-right">
                        <h5>* Email Address :</h5>
                         @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)*@
                         @Html.Editor("Email", @ViewData["Email"])
                         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-box-container">
                    <div class="form-box-left">
                        <h5>* Mobile No :</h5>
                        <select class="drop-item">
                            <option>India (+91)</option>
                        </select>
                        @*<input type="text" name="Mobile" onkeypress="CheckNumeric(event);" maxlength="10" />*@
                        @Html.Editor("Mobile", @ViewData["Mobile"])
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile)
                        <br>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-box-container">

                    <input type="submit" name="Post" value="Post" class="btm-bg" />

                </div>
            </section>
        </article>
    </fieldset>
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know where the problem is. I have changed my model as well for the required message but still no change has taken place and on submitting the post button the post back occurs without client-side validation.

Comment: have you include jquery.js file also..??

Comment: Hi Karthikeya.. yes I have inclluded them .. see the updated ques

Comment: first add jquery and then validation script. Also in your web.config app settings, do you have   <appSettings>
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings> ?

Comment: @SSA - I did earlier like jquery > validate.min.js> unobtrusive.min.js - then my jquery wasn't working. Then I changed it to validate.js and unobtrusive.js then jquery again started working but page is still posting back.

Comment: @SSA - and yes web.config has those settings true

Comment: First should be jquery, as validate depends on it. What is the problem if you add jquery first? are you loading jquery only once? And can you verify if all the scripts are there in browser.

Comment: reorder you js files...jquery-1.4.2.min.js should be at top

Comment: Order is ok now but problem is of error-messages which are not coming. Yes I'm loading jquery only once.

Comment: @Kartikeya - yes it is at the top now

Comment: @SSA -  I have some of the elements without html helpers like <input type = "text"...> in the page. Does it matter while validating ?

Comment: yes, they matter, because if you don't use MVC html helpers, the data tag required for validation will not be added on them, then you need to add them manually.

Comment: Can you add the final html generated for the form in browser in the post?

Comment: I am not able to edit it. it is very long. I can send it to you by email if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This sequence of your js calling

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What should I add here in logic to save ? I mean submit button is taking all values by itself.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey try changing the sequence of your js files validate.min.js and jquery.js .Also check after pressing F12 in chrome is there any error

Comment: @Smokingmonkey Please check the answer again I edit it for you.

Comment: I'm not able to load ..min.js file . It causes my page not to run the jquery. y is it so

Comment: Yes It is bcoz of that.I have tried your whole code on my side after rearranging js filesIt is working fine on my side.Please try to make sure your js path is correct.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: This sequence is only working when there is no .min added in between file name. otherwise its not. I have added the scripts  from nuget gallery. path is ok

Comment: Validation summary() is working now after cleaning the project but message is not appearing i front of the control after removing validationsummary()